# Align HTML Options with Right Edge of Parent Select

Tags: html, css

### Background:

I have a `select` which has a specified `width`. This `width` might be more narrow than some of the `options` inside it. What happens by default in that case is that the `option`s render as widely as necessary, and are aligned with the left edge of the `select`:

[image]

---

### Goal:

What I want to do is have the `option`s aligned to the right edge of the `select`, as shown in my mockup below:

[image]

---

### Question:

Is this possible to achieve with CSS? I've looked around and I've found a lot of answers about aligning the text inside, but it's the full `option` placement I want to tweak, so `text-align` won't work.

Comment: how about using a custom select plugin ?

Comment: I can build a custom dropdown if I have to, but it would be easier to just use a `select`.

Comment: i dont think its possible referring to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select

Comment: The functionality and rendering of many form components depend on default browser built-in features that are difficult and, some, impossible to alter. Go for a plugin/widget that basically will mimic this behavior using a div-span layout.
Consider CSS frameworks for the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research and reading the comments on this question, I have arrived at the conclusion that this cannot be done. The alignment **cannot be changed**, in any browser.

My workaround was to add a `button` beside the `input`, and style the two to look very similar. I used JS to power it, but I've been reading about the checkbox hack, so it could be done with no JS.

[image]